# Is autonav the most efficient pathing available?

Tags: naev

Will I be able to beat the autonav time wise if I manually navigated rather than letting it auto navigate via right click or will it always take the shortest possible path/time to my destination?

Assume I'm not using afterburners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've been able to tell, Autonav takes the most direct path, so it will take the absolute shortest amount of time. However, if Safe Lanes are implemented, this may change, as autonav would confine you to safe lanes, whereas you could leave the safe lanes on manual.

Also, +1 for playing Naev!